# Init derived class object using base class object

Tags: c++

I have the following types:

```
typedef std::vector<Node> Nodes;
struct Top: public Nodes {};
struct Middle: public Nodes {};
struct Bottom: public Nodes {};
```

Now lets say that my test class constructs a `Nodes` object called `_standardNodes`:

```
TestDifferentTypes(): _standardNodes(standardNodes(_model)) 
{
}
```

How do I create an instance of Top which is initialised with the data stored in nodes?

Comment: Remember that most of the standard classes are not meant to be inherited.

Comment: @StoryTeller In a test case method within the TestDifferentTypes class

Answer (score 2):

Inheriting vector is not a good idea; you want to have has-a relationship there, not is-a. Use parent `class NodeStore` which *has-a* `std::vector` of `Node` and inherit all other Node classes from it.

Then write an appropriate constructor (for each of those classes) that accepts each object type you need. It might look like this:

```
class NodeStore {
    std::vector<Node> m_nodes;

    std::vector<Node>& getNodes() { return m_nodes; }
}

class TopNode {
  TopNode ( NodeStore& store ): m_nodes(store.getNodes()) 
  {
  }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Inheriting from container types is generally avoided (for example, the destructor is not declared virtual, which means you need to be careful with polymorphism).  You should [prefer composition instead](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Composition_over_inheritance).

However, to answer your question, you'd need to define an appropriate constructor in `Top` which then invokes the appropriate base-class constructor:

```
struct Top : public Nodes {
    Top(const Nodes &rhs) : Nodes(rhs) {}
    ...
};
```

Answer (score 0):

You haven't shown us the use of `Nodes` and `Top`, `Middle` and
`Bottom`, but from the looks of things, I don't think this can
be made to work, for several reasons.

The most important reason is simple: a `std::vector<Node>` can
only contain objects of type `Node`.  Objects of type `Top`,
`Middle` and `Bottom` will be sliced (converted to `Node`) if
inserted, so you loose the derived type.

And you cannot do something like `struct Top : public
std::vector<Top>` (not that I think that's what you want), since
you cannot instantiate a vector over an incomplete type, and you
cannot derive from an uninstantiated template.

The usual solution for this is to create a `Tree` class, and use
`std::vector<Node*>` in the nodes (as a member, not via
inheritance).  Alternatively, you can use Boost's pointer vector
(but be careful of lifetime of the objects), or if you know that
you'll never need back pointers, you can use
`std::vector<std::unique_ptr<Node>>` (but the interface becomes
a little trickier, and you still need to be careful about the
lifetime of objects—removing an object from the tree will
destroy it).

Comment: @James Kanze I'm using a visitor pattern to visit Top, Middle, Bottom.